# Configure New Relic in IIS to show one application per domain

Tags: iis, newrelic

I am trying to understand how I can configure my .NET website to display each domain or groups of domains as Applications in the New Relic RPM console.

There is an article explaining here how to do it for PHP 
https://newrelic.com/docs/php/per-directory-settings

Comment: Could you maybe somewhat achieve the desired result by adding Custom Parameters to the transactions? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api - AddCustomParameter

Comment: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/how-do-i-monitor-multiple-web-applications-on-a-single-iis-host/198

Comment: @JohnLBevan the domains are part of the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At this time, the .NET agent doesn't support differentiating which
>   application to report to based on the hostname of each request.

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/report-websites-or-applications-running-in-the-same-iis-app-pool-as-different-new-relic-applications/36828

UPDATE December 2017: Please go to the URL above and vote for the feature if you think this feature would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

Applications can be named individually in the application's web config file. This is done by adding the following to the `<appSettings>` element:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="my_web_app" />
  <add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Multiple instances of an application can report to the same name in the New Relic UI by giving each application instance the same name as shown above.

Of course, you can separate applications by giving them different names.

You can use this naming feature to group application instances by name as you need. Your application instances can be running on the same server, on different servers, or on a mix of these.

See [this page](https://newrelic.com/docs/site/renaming-applications) for some additional information on application naming.

Note that you can also enable/disable monitoring of an application or application instance using the `NewRelic.AgentEnabled` key in the app settings section.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer my question - can I record activity coming in on different domains as different applications?

Comment: Not if they are using the same app pool/website.